# Using Ansible to login into a temporary interactive screen

Tags: bash, ansible

I have a few remote machines on which I need to execute some commands. I want to automate this using Ansible.

This is how the login into the remote machine works.

- I login using a username/password.
- Right after login (after it prints the last successful login etc) another interactive screen pops up asking on security question(please don't ask why but it is configured this way). Only after typing the answer can I execute commands on the machine.

Step 2 works similar to an interactive script put inside bash_profile.

I have RSA key pairs configured so Ansible can reach step 2. But in step 2 how can I type in the security answer using ansible before proceeding to other tasks.

Comment: You can use expect module, but then you need to run all commands through it. This is very similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41727489/2947502

Comment: But I am not running any commands on the remote host. I am still in the process of logging in. I got to the remote terminal after step 1 but no cli access yet. Is there a way to use expect module without running a command? Like just tell python to expect something when the code execution reached that point.

Comment: I understand what you do. Now, please understand what I wrote.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I type in the security answer using Ansible before proceeding to other tasks.

You can't without modifying Ansible code.

See also [an answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41731151/2947502).